# How do i resolve this error while running react-native project in Xcode?

Tags: ios, react-native

**Here is the log in Xcode**

```
2017-09-05 11:12:06.477 AppDemo[5064:29077] -[NSTaggedPointerString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa303036383231327
2017-09-05 11:12:06.642 AppDemo[5064:29077] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa303036383231327'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110564b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f41a141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105d4134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104eb840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104eb3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   AppDemo                             0x000000010e7cfc94 -[RCTMultipartStreamReader emitProgress:contentLength:final:callback:] + 244
    6   AppDemo                             0x000000010e7d048a -[RCTMultipartStreamReader readAllPartsWithCompletionCallback:progressCallback:] + 1610
    7   AppDemo                             0x000000010e81fdbc -[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:] + 444
    8   CFNetwork                           0x000000010ffc4c51 __88-[NSURLSession delegate_streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 51
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010ef243b7 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010ef240bb -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010ef22877 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 627
    12  Foundation                          0x000000010ef1e5fc __NSOQSchedule_f + 198
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011424605c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011422494f _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 221
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114225669 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1084
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114227ec4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 634
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114227bef _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001145dd712 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001145dd1ed start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: see this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15768

Comment: Seems like you need to update or reduce version of your RN

Comment: I guess your object is unsigned integer type and your are making  as string. Please check your object type. it is string or unsigned